# OTP page in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

How can i make otp page like this in flutter, kindly help me and share whole code for the specific photo thanks

[image]

Comment: Could you show your progress and what have you tried so far? SoF is not a website to share full code implementations for features, it is to help you with your struggles and your implementations in order to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Following Package in pubspec.yaml

```
otp_text_field:
  git:
    url: https://github.com/AkashMore7427/OTPTextField
```

Add the following import line in your dart file

```
import 'package:otp_text_field/otp_field.dart';
import 'package:otp_text_field/otp_field_style.dart';
import 'package:otp_text_field/style.dart';
```

Add the following code to your body

```
Column(children: [
    // Image.network("Add Image Link"),
    Text(
      "Enter verification Code",
    ),
    Text(
      "Code sent to info@gmail.com",
    ),
    OTPTextField(
        length: 4,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        fieldWidth: 50,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
        textFieldAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        onCompleted: (pin) {
          print("Completed: " + pin);
        },
        otpFieldStyle: OtpFieldStyle(
          borderColor: Colors.black,
        )),

    Text("Resend in 0:45"),
    //Add Button Widget Here
  ]),
```

[image]

Comment: Please give my answer to correct answer @Sher Khan Kakar

Comment: doesn't ask for accepting your answer. if it works for them then they accept your answer.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts in solving this question...

Comment: This is just a "OTP style widget", doesn't have any kind of logic. And adding a static "resend in x" sounds more like a UI challenge than actual help. If the author of the question thinks its valid, then it will be marked as correct, but don't ask for it.

Comment: @MOREAKASH Excellent brother and thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively for otp fields you can use [FlutterOtpField](https://pub.dev/packages/flutterotpfield) package where it provides `inputDecoration` property. With inputDecoration you can set your own design to OTP textFields.

Example:

```
FlutterOtpField(
              inputFieldLength: 4,
              spaceBetweenFields: 10,
              inputDecoration: InputDecoration(
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 46),
                  fillColor: Colors.transparent,
                  filled: true,
                  hintText: "#",
                  counterText: "",
                  hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff656565),
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                          color: Color(0xff969696),
                          width: 1.0),
                      borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                          color: Color(0xff969696),
                          width: 1.0),
                      borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.circular(30))),
              onValueChange: (String value) {
                print("otp changed $value");
              },
              onCompleted: (String value) {
                print("otp  $value");
              },)
```